# Is there any way to fix the frequency of bluetooth communication?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3, hci

I need to get my bluetooth device certified by the regulatory authorities. It basically works on raspberry pi. They want the bluetooth to broadcast on a single frequency for verifying if its going outside of the unlicensed spectrum or not.

Is there any tool on linux using which I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Being under Linux, I'll assume you're using a standard bluetooth dongle using standard Host Controller Interface (HCI). This is the case for most (if not all) USB dongles.

HCI commands and parameters are defined in [Core specification document](https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=421043), in Vol 2, Part E, Chapter 7. You can send them to a HCI device with Bluez' `hcitool(1)` command line utility, that has a `cmd` subcommand allowing to send raw commands to any HCI-compliant device.

LE test commands defined in 2.E.7.8.{28,29,30} allow you to send predefined packets on fixed radio channels. Test scenarios Message Sequence Charts for BLE are in 6.F.2.